# Using Summary function inside Data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning `data.table` using examples and I am stuck-up with my own scenario.

I am using `cars` dataset and converted to a `data.table` for trying my commands.

```
library(data.table)
> cars.dt=data.table(cars)
> cars.dt[1:5]
   speed dist
1:     4    2
2:     4   10
3:     7    4
4:     7   22
5:     8   16
.
.
```

I wanted to calculate the summary statistics for each group of `speed` and store it in different columns but the values are stored in multiple rows.

e.g

```
 > cars.dt[, summary(dist), by="speed"]
      speed V1
   1:     4  2
   2:     4  4
   3:     4  6
   4:     4  6
   5:     4  8
  ---         
 110:    25 85
 111:    25 85
 112:    25 85
 113:    25 85
 114:    25 85
```

I was expecting the below output and I am unable to achieve it.

```
    speed   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 1:     4      2       4       6       6       8      10 
 2:     7    4.0     8.5    13.0    13.0    17.5    22.0 
 3:     8     16      16      16      16      16      16 
 4:     9     10      10      10      10      10      10 
 5:    10     18      22      26      26      30      34 
 6:    11  17.00   19.75   22.50   22.50   25.25   28.00 
 7:    12   14.0    18.5    22.0    21.5    25.0    28.0 
 8:    13     26      32      34      35      37      46 
 9:    14   26.0    33.5    48.0    50.5    65.0    80.0 
10:    15  20.00   23.00   26.00   33.33   40.00   54.00 
11:    16     32      34      36      36      38      40 
12:    17  32.00   36.00   40.00   40.67   45.00   50.00 
13:    18   42.0    52.5    66.0    64.5    78.0    84.0 
14:    19     36      41      46      50      57      68 
15:    20   32.0    48.0    52.0    50.4    56.0    64.0 
16:    22     66      66      66      66      66      66 
17:    23     54      54      54      54      54      54 
18:    24  70.00   86.50   92.50   93.75   99.75  120.00 
19:    25     85      85      85      85      85      85
```

I tried the below command but the output was not in a data.table

```
> cars.dt[, print(summary(dist)), by="speed"] 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      2       4       6       6       8      10 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    4.0     8.5    13.0    13.0    17.5    22.0 
...
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  70.00   86.50   92.50   93.75   99.75  120.00 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     85      85      85      85      85      85 
 Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: speed
```

I am unable to use functions returning multiple values when using `by` clause.

If anyone has any idea as to how to write this, it would be much appreciated.

Also let me know if this possible in data.table

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
 dt1 <- cars.dt[, as.list(summary(dist)), by="speed"]
 head(dt1)
 #    speed Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
 #1:     4    2    4.00    6.0  6.0    8.00   10
 #2:     7    4    8.50   13.0 13.0   17.50   22
 #3:     8   16   16.00   16.0 16.0   16.00   16
 #4:     9   10   10.00   10.0 10.0   10.00   10
 #5:    10   18   22.00   26.0 26.0   30.00   34
 #6:    11   17   19.75   22.5 22.5   25.25   28
```

You could also consider `summaryBy` from `doBy` to have some control over the summary functions to output.

```
 library(doBy)
 dt2 <- summaryBy(.~speed, cars.dt, FUN=c(min, median, mean, max))
 head(dt2,2)
 #   speed dist.min dist.median dist.mean dist.max
 #1:     4        2           6         6       10
 #2:     7        4          13        13       22
```

I guess the difference in `as.list` and `list` argument is:

Without the grouping variable

```
 list(summary(cars.dt$speed))  #this gets a `list` with one `list element`
 #[[1]]
 # Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 4.0    12.0    15.0    15.4    19.0    25.0 

as.list(summary(cars.dt$speed)) #whereas this is also a list with multiple elements
# $Min.
#[1] 4

#$`1st Qu.`
#[1] 12

 #$Median
 #[1] 15

#$Mean
#[1] 15.4

#$`3rd Qu.`
#[1] 19

#$Max.
#[1] 25
```

same as `list(1:5)` and `as.list(1:5)`

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly as expected. But any idea why as.list works and not list ??